# Different Google oAuth page depending of login-hint parameter

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I'm developing an app that uses the oAuth authentication for Google accounts. The problem is that depending of the login-hint that I'm sending to the page (@gmail.com or @googleappsdomains.com) the page has an appearance or another.

My question is... Is there any way to load always the same oAuth page and not a different one depending of domain (login-hint will always be send as a param, is not a solution to not send this param).

Answer (score 0):

I think login-hint is working as intended.  If the browser is logged into multiple Google accounts (and a lot of them are), if there’s no login-hint, then the person is going to see the Google AccountChooser, asking them which account they want to use. If login-hint is there and they’re logged into that account, things just go straight ahead.  There are other sources of variation... depending whether or not they’ve previously approved your scopes in the login-hint account, they might or might not get an approval screen, and depending whether or not they’re actually logged into that account, they might or might not get a sign-in flow.

So your objective (always having the same flow) is probably quite hard to achieve.  I’d ask myself if it’s worthwhile, because these flows are quite carefully designed and work pretty well.